# find default java cacerts file

Tags: windows-10, java, path, certificate

java & keytool install paths:

```
C:\Users\foobar>where java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe

C:\Users\foobar>where keytool
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\keytool.exe
```

As it's the only `cacerts` file in the `Java` directory, I assume this is the default:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

`keytool` output - WITH path to specific `cacerts` keystore file:

```
C:\Users\foobar>keytool -list -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 98 entries

verisignclass2g2ca [jdk], Aug 25, 2016, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): C9:B4:1C:EA:F2:9D:95:B6:CC:A0:08:1B:67:EC:9D:B3:EA:C4:47:76
digicertassuredidg3 [jdk], Aug 25, 2016, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 00:F4:9F:DC:0F:48:2C:AB:30:89:F5:17:A2:4F:9A:48:C6:C9:F8:A2
...
...
...
verisignuniversalrootca [jdk], Aug 25, 2016, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 36:30:A5:FB:87:3B:0F:A7:7B:B7:0D:54:79:CA:35:66:87:72:30:4D
```

`keytool` output - WITHOUT path to specific `cacerts` keystore file:

```
C:\Users\foobar>keytool -list
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 0 entries
```

Why are the `keytool` outputs not the same?

When a specific keystore is NOT defined, which `cacerts` file is being used/referenced?

Answer (score 1):

Although radical and apparently almost totally unknown, you *could* consider looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html):

> **Common Options**
>
> **-keystore *keystore***
>
> ... if [not] specified, the default keystore file named `.keystore` [] in the user's home directory ...

(although the qualification stated -- 'If the JKS storetype is used' -- is imprecise; this behavior and default applies to all file-based storetypes. JKS is the default through 8, but in 9 up the default is changed to PKCS12, and both are file-based.)

The [Java 11 doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html) is even more specific; it adds:

> Examples of Option Values
>
> The following examples show the defaults for various option values:
>
> ...
>
> `-keystore <the file named .keystore in the user's home directory>`

PS: You might also want to know that on current Windows -- since Vista or maybe Seven, I don't recall exactly -- if you install to the default locations under `\Program Files [(x86)]` then trying to *modify* that `cacerts` (to add your own CA for example) may not work. Windows really doesn't like people manually changing any files in those subtrees and will usually 'virtualize' them so that your write operation appears to work but the file does not actually change. (I *believe* changes made by Group Policy do work, but I am not in a Windows domain so I can't check that.) If you install somewhere else you don't have this problem.

PPS: also found a crossdupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980364/how-do-i-find-out-what-keystore-my-jvm-is-using

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by accident - The default referenced file is here:

```
C:\Users\foobar\.keystore
```

I imagine this might vary depending on how/where you install java.